# Ldap + Php exemplo de conexao

Tags: php

Estou tentando fazer uma simples conexão e pegar se determinado usuário esta no ldap.

Porem não estou conseguindo, pesquisei na net e não encontrei nenhum script sequer que me ajudasse.

Comment: Quando você diz "pegar", quer dizer "autenticar"? Ou apenas saber se existe?

Comment: Para que tipo de aplicação você queria? Você quer realizar autenticação ou apenas realizar uma consulta de usuário no LDAP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php#refsect1-function.ldap-bind-examples

Comment: Saber se existe o usuario, e também gostaria de pegar todos os usuario do diretorio

Comment: Por favor, poste o código que você está utilizando e explique qual a dificuldade.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma biblioteca que ja utilizei em um projeto, ela chama [adLDAP](https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP)

**EXEMPLO**

```
$config = array(
    'account_suffix' => "@gatech.edu",

    'domain_controllers' => array("whitepages.gatech.edu"),

    'base_dn' => 'dc=whitepages,dc=gatech,dc=edu',

    'admin_username' => '',

    'admin_password' => '',
);

$ad = new Adldap($config);
```